# Enable cross-site tracking in WKWebView

Tags: ios, wkwebview

When compiling against the iOS 11 SDK, it seems as though the default cookie accept policy for `WKWebView` has changed, as though the user had enabled the equivalent "Prevent Cross-Site Tracking" option in Safari.

I need cross-site cookies to work within a `WKWebView`. Does anyone know of a way to enable this please?

Answer (score 4):

For enterprise app deployments (i.e. distribution outside the App Store), you can use the following private method on `WKProcessPool`:

`self.webView.configuration.processPool.perform("_setCookieAcceptPolicy:", with: HTTPCookie.AcceptPolicy.always)`

The corresponding WebKit source code can be found here:

https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/c637754ee7dfca6142e441d2040026903fee0c1f/Source/WebKit/UIProcess/API/Cocoa/WKProcessPool.mm

Comment: THANK YOU. Saved my and my team's butt asses =D

Comment: Just to re-iterate - this is NOT App Store safe, as it uses a private API.

Comment: Guess apple doesn't support this as an option anymore?